# Why do my questions get so few views?

Tags: discussion, questions, views

I posted [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944702/python-c-api-define-a-template-for-the-creation-of-extension-types) on Stack Overflow three days ago, and I have also put a bounty on it, but it is still not receiving a decent amount of views.

I can't understand why, and I also noticed that it didn't happen with just this question, but with the previous two or three that I asked. It gives me the feeling that somehow Stack Overflow tries to limit my interactions with the community. What's wrong with my questions?

Comment: With a title like *"Python C api: define a “template” for the creation of extension types"* I can see many avoiding it as it looks more like a "write the code for me" *'question'* rather than a "I am stuck with this problem, how to do resolve it?" question. The title is the first thing many are going to see when you post a question, and thus your question will be judged by it. Write a title that makes it look like a request, and not a question, and people aren't going to be interested.

Comment: SO never limits the visibility of a question unless it gets several downvotes. There is no algorithm in place which artificially modifies how often a question is listed.

Comment: Of course, you'll get plenty of views now, due to the meta effect; but that doesn't mean you'll get any answers. :)

Comment: @Larnu I think the main problem with my question is that I don't really know what I am looking for. To overcome this problem I should explain the final goal, but it is not something that can be summed up in a title.

Comment: Working out what *you* need is really important before asking. If you don't know what you need, @Giuppox , it's unlikely we (the other users) are going to know.

Comment: @Larnu do you think something like "How to efficiently define Python-C extension types" would be better?

Comment: It, at least, looks like a question in my eyes, @Giuppox .

Comment: Besides some common readability things - how many people will effectively have knowledge of the Python C API I wonder, it seems like a kind of niche thing. If you use Python then you will generally want to use purely Python. When something is a niche topic you likely have a very small target audience I'm afraid. Not much to be done about that.

Comment: @Gimby actually python's C api – i think – is not a niche thing at all. Python is written in C, and like all the other interpreted languages is quite slow. That's why all the most important python libraries (e.g. numpy, tensorflow or pytorch) are written wrapping C code inside Python (that makes things a quite a lot faster!). Python builtin libraries are sometimes written in C!

Comment: @Giuppox yet the tag has only 1500 questions, as compared to the python tag which has 1.6 million questions. People using Python are not generally in the business of writing libraries for Python, that itself is restricted to a subset - the size of which I am not going to claim I am capable to know. Push comes to shove cross-over questions (Python and C in this case) are difficult beasts, you have to be lucky to get that one person who is passionate about all aspects involved AND happens to see your question AND happens to know the answer. The odds are not in your favor.

Comment: I agree that your topic is a niche.  Just because Python is written in C, and libraries often make use of C code, doesn't mean that a lot of the population understands any of that.  The general topic of creating distributed modules at all is already a bit of a niche, as most users will never do that. Then to add the C extension requirement only lowers the audience further.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII - nothing wrong with that if that is the case.  The "meta effect" was already mentioned.  It's not like there's a limited supply of "views". - In other words...there's no reason to not want the OP to get a good answer to their question.

Comment: I have de-walled the original question's text. The presentation of a question, e.g., breaking it down into digestible chunks, can go a long ways. The bottom line is that you're asking a question that most people likely can't answer.

Comment: I saw your question, I know python and even have done some small coding in C for it, and I know C very well. But I still don't know an answer that would help you. So I guess the main problem with this kind of questions is indeed the "niche thing".

Comment: After reading through your question a couple times, I still have no idea what you are actually asking. It seems that possible answers could fall anywhere between "use the standard library module X" to "take a seat for our 24 lesson course on building a JIT compiler". Seeing how an answer in these tags is going to be some work, going to extra mile of figuring out what the question even is does not seem particularly attractive.

Comment: Even if correlated, getting views and getting answers are two different things. You could get views from c/python tag watchers and answers from a small subset of both (or python-c-api watchers, but they saw your question already). The title of the question is clear enough, so most people know they cannot answer without reading the question - thus there aren’t many views, but this is not really a bad thing per se: getting views from people not being able to solve or understand your question doesn’t help your cause much and might lead to (more) downvotes

Comment: Your question was seen by people who would be able to answer, but they have chosen not to interact with it - which means the question is either unclear or not interesting enough. Adding some bounty will not change much, without improving the question itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let me preface that I'm not a domain expert other than knowing a bit of Python and C. I can speculate on a few reasons why this question isn't answered in spite of the bounty:

#### Niche tag

The [python-c-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-c-api) tag is niche, judging by the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-c-api/topusers). You might think it wouldn't be, because Python is an extremely popular language, but the fact is, most people using it don't dig into the source code or extend it (I have looked at the source before but haven't written extensions in 5 years of using the language). Libraries like NumPy solve the vast majority of use cases for numerical computing without need to open the hood or reinvent the wheel.

This tag has 1200 questions with 60% unanswered in the last 30 days. For comparison, NumPy has [90k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) questions at the time of writing. Some niche tags are babysat by a user or two that makes an effort to answer most questions, but this doesn't appear to be the case here.

[One power user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala) has answered 2 questions in this tag in the past 30 days, and has answered 13 questions in the tag overall. A second user has answered 1 question in the past 30 days. If we assume a couple of extra users who have the knowledge to answer these questions but haven't recently, it appears you have an audience of about, say, 4 or 5 prospective answerers before even looking at your question.

#### Text-only question

I'd guess that text-only posts like this tend to be skipped heavily. Most people on the site are working with code, and if some don't see any, even a small excerpt, it's an instant click-away. Even if your post is good and otherwise brief, you're guilty by association with the thousands of posts every day that are missing context and a [minimal, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The standard for code inclusion might be lower for this tag, so it's a good idea to look at the [most highly-voted questions in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-c-api?tab=Votes) and follow suit to the extent that makes sense.

#### Presumes knowledge

Your post says

> I have managed to create something acceptable simply by following <link to enormous page of text from the docs>.

...followed by no code excerpt or guidance on which sections of the link are relevant. Your post adds

> Since numpy implements the exact same thing I thought about taking a look at <link to NumPy source code file with 4200 lines of code>

...with no code snippets, line numbers or any example of what you're referring to other than `@varname`.

In other words, of the audience of 4-5, you're basically assuming they are already familiar with what you're asking conceptually. Maybe this is common knowledge for tag users, but it can't hurt to describe your problem in a way that anyone reasonably familiar with Python and C (such as myself) would know what you mean. It'd probably take me about 45 minutes to an hour just to figure out what you're asking, by working through the tutorial and then digging through the NumPy source, and probably making a lot of guesses about your particular use case.

#### Poor prospect of ROI?

Answerers need some sort of ROI on taking the time to write an answer to a question like this. It's doubtful that anyone will upvote their answer more than +1 or +2 (although it looks like you have a very strong accept rate on your questions, which is great -- yes, some answerers *do* take that into consideration because there are many ask-then-disappear question authors). Sure, there's a bounty, but I bet the power user or two in this tag doesn't care much about 50 rep. They can easily get that by knocking out a couple of random questions that are much more clear-cut and likely to reach a wider audience.

I can see a few users being into this sort of question for personal interest or happening to know the answer, but that's about all that's going for it. It may not be low-hanging fruit for the tag and doesn't smell like the sort of question that would someday become a [canonical, often-searched question for the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-c-api?tab=Votes). It seems rather opinion-based and code review-y, as you're looking to DRY some invisible code out.

#### No better solution?

Given that NumPy is an industry standard Python library, maybe the way they're solving this problem isn't so hackish as you suppose and prospective answerers genuinely have no better alternative to offer.

Long story short, it's not surprising to me that nobody from the miniscule pool of possible answerers for the tag bothered with this one.

Comment: I have just edited my question, i hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Thanks. Hope you get some clarity on it from the comments/extra meta attention, if not an answer. I realize your meta question here is more focused on views (you can blame the niche tag for that), but at this point it's had plenty of them so I figured better to talk about the post itself.

Comment: I think this describes the situation correctly. In niche tags, SO is still pure: the quality of the question counts more - people aren’t motivated to answer by possible rep gains ( those gains are negligible no matter how great the answer) but out of curiosity/interest. Improving question helps more than adding a bounty.